# How to define an object type that does _not_ include a specific member

Tags: typescript

I am working with objects I put in and out of databases/actions and sometimes wish to add and remove database/action-specific fields.

For example, I have:

```
type EntryEvent<EntryLine> = { type: 'entry' } & EntryLine;
```

Elsewhere I wish to drop the `type` member in order to turn an `EntryEvent<EntryLine>` back into an `EntryLine`. To do that I use a utility function as follows:

```
export function stripFields<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(
  o: T,
  fields: K[]
): Omit<T, K> {
  const result: Partial<T> = { ...(<object>o) };
  for (const field of fields) {
    delete result[field];
  }
  return <Omit<T, K>>result;
}
```

The trouble is, the resulting object won't be recognized as an `EntryLine`.

If I try to assign the following to an `EntryLine` type:

```
stripFields(event, ['type'])
```

I will get:

```
Argument of type 'Pick<EntryEvent<EntryLine>, Exclude<keyof EntryLine, "type">>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EntryLine'.
  'Pick<EntryEvent<EntryLine>, Exclude<keyof EntryLine, "type">>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'EntryLine', but 'EntryLine' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Pick<object, never>' ts(2345)
```

As far as I can tell that makes sense, because if the generic type `EntryLine` included a `type` member, the result of `stripFields` would no longer be an `EntryLine` (since it would be missing its `type` member).

Is there some way I can define constrain the generic type `EntryLine` so that it does not allow objects with a `type` field? Or is there some other means of working around this?

**Update:**

The following code reproduces the problem for me:

```
type EntryEvent<EntryLine> = { type: "entry" } & EntryLine;

type MyEntryLine = {
  a: Date;
};

export function stripFields<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(
  o: T,
  fields: K[]
): Omit<T, K> {
  const result: Partial<T> = { ...(<object>o) };
  for (const field of fields) {
    delete result[field];
  }
  return <Omit<T, K>>result;
}

type Callback<EntryLine> = (a: EntryLine) => void;

function thingThatTakesAnEvent<EntryLine>(a: EntryEvent<EntryLine>, callback: Callback<EntryLine>) {
  callback(stripFields(a, ["type"]));
}

function thingThatTakesAMyEntryLine(a: MyEntryLine) {
  console.log(a.a);
}

declare let event: EntryEvent<MyEntryLine>;

thingThatTakesAnEvent(event, thingThatTakesAMyEntryLine);
```

[Playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdsATiGA3CCA88kgDICWcEAfFALxQDeUokAXFAEQa5NQC+UAZLAsoWIBuAFAi60ALIp++ItEpURUKAENGAEVXAIojqJEQAHmAD2iYFABmAVzgBjYAVNwoAZyQEwAMQIQANgAmbpgAKlDGOnDBUKYARgBWEI4ANFAA0hFGUTEA1hAgplZQoSQAFMqxjKEplVZ+QW6M6QDaALoiAJSMAPIAtgTAYWnpZEoq9i4eUIgQbjb+wIwACqoWBKr+YWSKUAB0B2WY8UmOJKadnKIqVuZQZZNw0-UBgbHFL42X4ypQgQEQHQzOYLYAtT6BNrXTiVWbAGyIVyYfqDYYZEgkWbzRZ6MQSKAAYU2-jiqnsuWwskEpAo93UfFw1Mu5DIqFMBECBlsDicLloAAsiABzUL87ShVT5NwAQTgaFYlMZ8nK9JwyHlWDVcmIJDS9mJpPJjCJ-hJZIpWupJG+lX1psNuTKHkQXl8rzcZVUaRaTAkTDanU6uJE3MczlcwEFcBFYuAEql0uklvknsYSap8htEympn8ED2-lMQs9e1UQZEHDE-3s-jW0Dzlgg6AQjC1GqG6aVOoMkeFovFkrmsvbZSbrDSvej-bjg5lnYEmaEQA)

Comment: Can't reproduce your error. Is there something you do different than [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdsATiGA3CCA88kgDICWcEAfFALxQDeUokAXFAEQa5NQC+UAZLAsoWIBuAFAi60ALIp++ItEpURUKAENGAEVXAIojqJEQAHmAD2iYFABmAVzgBjYAVNwoAZyQEwAMQIQANgAmbpgAKlDGOnDBUKYARgBWEI4ANFAA0hFGUTEA1hAgplZQoSQAFMqxjKEplVZ+QW6M6QDaALoiAJSMAPIAtgTAYWnpZEoq9i4eUIgQbjb+wIwACqoWBKr+YWSKUAB0B2WY8UmOJKadnKIqVuZQZZNw0-UBgbHFL42X4ypQgQEQHQzOYLYAtT6BNrXTiVWbAGyIVyYfqDYYZEgkWbzRZ6MT-ez+NbQfyAiLoBCMHDINCsTDSKlyYgkAyPaaWSgeRBeXyvNxlCDk4BpFpMCRMNqdUTAPaqURAA)?

Comment: I have created a test case to reproduce this but I can't post it because the URL is too long for the comment and SO doesn't allow URLs from shorteners so let me edit the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 'Pick< EntryEvent< EntryLine>, Exclude< keyof EntryLine, "type">>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'EntryLine', but 'EntryLine' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'.

Error messages in this form basically mean, that you tried to infer too much from the passed in generic type parameter, whose exact type only the caller/client can know. Typescript does not consider your speculations about its type to be safe anymore.

Concerning your code, it could be translated to this:

```
function thingThatTakesAnEvent<EntryLine>(
  a: EntryEvent<EntryLine>,
  callback: Callback<EntryLine>
) {
  callback(stripFields(a, ["type"]));
           //------ error ------//
}
```

==> the return type of `stripFields`, which is `Pick< EntryEvent< EntryLine>, Exclude< keyof EntryLine, "type">>`, is assignable to the constraint `EntryLine` (which defaults here to `{}`), but what if the caller invoked the function like this: `thingThatTakesAnEvent<{foo: "bar"}>` ? Inside the function we cannot know that it's `{foo: "bar"}`, and we should invoke `callback` with `EntryLine`, but we did with a specific subtype, which may be not the right one from the caller.

Based on the purpose, you could do the following:

1. Change your Callback type to match the type of `stripFields` [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdsATiGA3CCA88kgDICWcEAfFALxQDeUokAXFAEQa5NQC+UAZLAsoWIBuAFAi60ALIp++ItEpURUKAENGAEVXAIojqJEQAHmAD2iYFABmAVzgBjYAVNwoAZyQEwAMQIQANgAmbpgAKlDGOnDBUKYARgBWEI4ANFAA0hFGUTEA1hAgplZQoSQAFMqxjKEplVZ+QW6M6QDaALoiAJSMAPIAtgTAYWnpZEoqAPQTUBqmUHCmlsQQgbRz9qoeUAAWEIgQAHSV9i5b+242-paKUAd3c-p15lBlJ3Bb9QGrRdYNwZ3USoqQIBCA6KDnS7AFqfIJtUQqDiVfbAGyIVyQq56MQSKAAYVU-n8cVU9ly2FkglIFBe6ig-UGFNwaFYTIE8hIaSYEiYJAB5DIqFMBECBlsDicLlo2yIAHNQtttKFVPk3ABBOAsrA4dnEcqVOk6lDobWUjm1FQbIkksmMAnW0nko1UkhdQGWwnEx1lDyILy+L5uMqqNItbngCBMNqdTrYkTixzOVzAGVweWK4DK1Vq6TO+TBxi5s3EAHjKBvNymfyHfymWXBg6qWMiJEiEH2fyqfZQauWCAm4CMI1aoZF3AugwpuUKpUqiDqzUDsr91hpKdpmeZufqse6iCxoA):

```
type Callback<EntryLine> = (a: Omit<EntryEvent<EntryLine>, "type">) => void;
```

2. Do a cast in `thingThatTakesAndEvent` [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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):

```
function thingThatTakesAnEvent<EntryLine>(
  a: EntryEvent<EntryLine>,
  callback: Callback<EntryLine>
) {
  callback((stripFields(a, ["type"]) as unknown) as EntryLine);
}
```

Comment: I'm probably getting confused with C++ templates, but if we invoke `thingThatTakesAnEvent<{foo: "bar"}>` then wouldn't the type of `callback` be `Callback<{foo: "bar"}>`? I'm having trouble working out where TypeScript is getting tripped up but I guess what you're saying is that within `thingThatTakesAnEvent` TypeScript treats `EntryEvent<EntryLine>` as an opaque type?

Comment: @brianskold What you say is right concerning `callback`. TS gets tripped, because the `callback` expects an unconstrained generic type argument `EntryLine` (TS defaults to `{}` type here, see the error), but `stripFields` returns `Omit<EntryEvent<EntryLine>, "type">`, which equals to `Pick<EntryEvent<EntryLine>, Exclude<keyof EntryLine, "type">>`. So *technically* it is not exactly the same type as `EntryLine`.

Comment: E.g. what if `EntryLine` itself would have a `type` property? The `stripFields` return type would exclude this property and you would not pass original `EntryLine` type in callback anymore. Thats why TS complains. So in situations like yours it is perfectly fine and reasonable to help the compiler a bit and cast the type like in example2.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. The problem of "what if `EntryLine` itself would have a `type` property" is precisely the problem I initially went out to solve but I suppose it's simply not possible with TS at this point in time.

Comment: Yeah, that's unfortunately not possible, if you want to keep `EntryEvent` as intersection type like above. There is no way to distinguish the `type` properties of the two constituents.